# RequireJs - First attempt - Cant seem to get it right

Tags: requirejs

So I'm trying to set up using RequireJs based on John Papa's Code Camper Tutorial on PlurarlSight, but I still cant seem to get it right.

My bootstrapper.run() never gets called because bs is always undefined

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/jquery.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/libs/knockout-2.2.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/libs/toastr-1.1.5.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/libs/require.js")
```

Scripts/main.js

```
(function() {
var root = this;
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts/libs',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
Define3rdPartyModules();
LoadPluginsAndBoot();

function Define3rdPartyModules() {
    //Load things such as jquery, ko, Kendo, toastr etc here
    define('jquery', [], function () { return root.jQuery; });
    define('knockout', [], function () { return root.ko; });
    define('toastr', [], function () { return root.toastr; });
    define('kendo', [], function() { return root.kendo; });
}

function LoadPluginsAndBoot() {
    //Load self create plugins and extensions here
    requirejs(['app/ko-bindingHandlers', 'app/ko-kendo'], Boot);
}

function Boot() {

  require(['app/bootstrapper'], 
    function (bs) {
        bs.run();
    });
}

})();
```

Scripts/app/bootstrapper.js

```
define('bootstrapper',
[],
function () {

  var run = function () {
    alert('we ran this');
  };

  return { run: run };
});
```

bootstrapper.js shows up in my dev console window, yet bs is undefined.

Also I'm trying to use the ko-kendo extension that Ryan Niemeyer created and I see that it has built in requirejs checks, so should I be defining that in my _Layout.cshtml or keep it where it is?

Comment: Usually you don't include the name of a module when using the define call. `define([], function() { ... });` Usually this is added in by the optimiser - Not sure if this is a fix to your issue though...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment on my question. I haven't gotten to try your suggestion as of yet but I will shortly. Hopefully I can come back on here and have you make it an official answer :D